# Tufte-handout without margin

Tags: fonts, templates

I just started to write LaTeX document with "tufte-handout". The interesting thing I found was the look-up of output.

I did this one:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
{\bf Example.} $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ has no non-trivial ideals if char $F\neq 2$. 
If Char $F=2$ then center is non-trivial and is a non-trivial ideal.
\end{document}
```

The output was of the following form: **please ignore left and top column.**

> [image]

Notice that theere is too much space on the right side of the output file. Perhaps, this is an important feature of "tufte-handout" - to keep space on right for remarks, notes, comments etc.
It (font) is much different (and looks beautiful to me) than usual roman font.

**What do I want:** I wanted to write my documents in the above font-style.  But I don't want to leave space on right-side for remarks, notes etc. With "tufte-handout" or other way, how can I do this?

In other words, I want to write very-commonly type of document-typing, but with condition that, the font should be of above type only.

In short, I want **the font same as in above output file** and **document without margins (as like book-writing or notes typing)**

Answer (score 6):

The font used by `tufte-handout` can be loaded with *any* other document class as well by saying

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
```

If you also want to mimic the sans-serif and mono font styles, add these

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.90]{helvet}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
```

---

Full example with the `article` document class

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Example.} $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ has no non-trivial ideals if
char $F\neq 2$.  If Char $F=2$ then center is non-trivial and is a
non-trivial ideal.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 The example with article is fantastic! Thanks too much!

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, yes, this is an important feature of `tufte-handout`. I think it's worth seeing [this example](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-handout.pdf) to understant why.

If you do not want that style *except the fonts*, then  the most reasonable is use another class (Heri's answer). If you want that class for another reasons (table of contents, etc.) but you are pretty sure that you *never ever will use the right margin*, then Martin's could have sense. But as showed in the cited example, you do not have to give up on this feature to use in some part the full width of the page. Simply use the `fullwidth` environment:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
{\bfseries Example.} $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ has no non-trivial ideals 
if char $F\neq 2$.  If Char $F=2$ then center is non-trivial and is 
a non-trivial ideal.
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Note: Please do not use `\bf` but the safer `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package to adapt page margins:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=23mm, left=28mm, right=46mm, bottom=46mm, headsep=1em,
          marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=1em}
\begin{document}
{\bf Example.} $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ has no non-trivial ideals if char $F\neq 2$.
If Char $F=2$ then center is non-trivial and is a non-trivial ideal.
\end{document}
```